# Accessing Outlook Address Book

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, outlook, com

I have a Delphi XE app and I'd like to pop up the address book dialog that Outlook uses from within my Delphi app - I assume there are COM classes to support this? What's the best way to get this done? Platform is Win7-64 with Outlook 2010.

TIA

Comment: Are you tied to COM stuff? Exchange Web Services would be the preferred way to do this these days.

Comment: I know about Exchange Web Services but a traditional programming approach is better for me in this context.